# Can anyone explain what features of the C runtime in Android (via NDK) are not supported?

Tags: c++, android, stl, java-native-interface, android-ndk

More specifically, does NDK have a complete STL implementation. We're looking at this for devices running 1.6 and upwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the only [supported libraries in the NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) at this time are:

- `libc`
- `libm`
- `libz` (Zlib compression)
- `liblog` (Android logging)
- OpenGL ES 1.1 and OpenGL ES 2.0 (3D graphics libraries)

Also available are interfaces for JNI and **minimal C++ support**.

Answer (score 1):

As of ndk 5 there is a variety of stl options with and without exception handling.

[NDK page on android developer](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html)

Comment: Yes, they've finally added STL (so if you're building C++ code with NDK, things are a little easier now - previously we had to hack the NDK to build stuff :-)